# How solve this $\log { { x }^{ \log _{ x }{ y } } } =\quad \frac { 5 }{ 2 } \\ x+y=6\\ $

Tags: logarithms

How solve this logarithm equation

$\log { { x }^{ \log _{ x }{ y }  } } =\quad \frac { 5 }{ 2 } \\ x+y=6\\ $

Comment: Hint: $x^{\log_x y}=y$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$\log _{ x }{ y }=\frac{\log (y)}{\log (x)}$ then $\log { { x }^{ \log _{ x }{ y }  } }=\log (y)$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Comment: Or more simply, $\log_x(y)$ is by definition a number $t$ such that $x^t = y$.